# How to make sure correct .BUD files are generated for print driver after a Windows Upgrade

Tags: windows, printing, windows-10, wdk, virtual-printer

After upgrading Windows 10 anniv. to Windows 10 creators update my own virtual printer (based on unidrv) is unavailable. When I select it in control panel I get a dialog to install a driver (which I ignore) and by pressing cancel you see the printer properties which are readonly (unavailable).

The problem seems to be related to an incorrect .BUD file being generated. When replacing the incorrectly generated .BUD file after the Creators upgrade with a .BUD file (saved after getting the printer driver working) the driver works. (tested this by doing update restore etc..)
Via process monitor I see one access denied followed by lots of success for the CreateFile operation for .BUD files.

So I was wondering: why is that .BUD file generated incorrectly?

While searching I've found this https://superuser.com/questions/17981/why-is-my-current-printer-unavailable-in-office/70477#70477 which guides you to https://web.archive.org/web/20150511125304/https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;873396

Quote from the KB:

> "This problem occurs because you do not have the permissions that are
>   required to create or re-create a parsed binary printer description
>   file (.bud).  "

Has anyone experience with this? I'm looking for a way to prevent that such a .BUD file for the printer driver is incorrectly generated after a major Windows Upgrade.

Are there things that should be added to the registry or specific files on the pc to make sure that upgrading Windows doesn't make the printer driver invalid?
Or how do you make sure the driver automatically has all correct permissions?

Hopefully there are some experts here on SO that can show the real cause and how to prevent it.